# mysql storage filling up unexpectedly (RDS)

Tags: mysql, storage, database, amazon-rds

I am total newbie to database game.
& I am using mysql 8.0 RDS 20GB free tier.

I don't have much data on it.(**just 300 Mb**)

But I always get a mail that **you have exceeded 85% of storage limit.**(approx 17Gb)

Also Under *monitoring* tab in rds panel it shows:- **Free Storage Space (MB) = 19.330Gb**

**I have turned off :** *general log, slow logs, binlog,*

Can someone please help me whats consuming these storage. Is this something to do with INNODB?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for at least your biggest table.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62098640/13646178 @RickJames can you please join this dicussion?

Comment: Additional information request. 
AWS RDS model in use, Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
G) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: I anyone who's interested,
can join this question-answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/62098640/13646178)